# DataWeave 2.0: Concatenate within a child syntax error

Tags: transformation, mule-studio, dataweave

I'm playing around with "dataweave" in mulesoft studio. The code below works just fine

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    theId: payload01.Id,
    theName: payload01.Name,
    contacts: payload01.Contacts map ( contact , indexOfContact ) -> {
        contactName: contact.name
    }
}
```

but when I replace

```
contactName: contact.name
```

with

```
contactName: contact.name ++ "XXX"
```

I get a syntax error about the following:

```
    Reason:
    - 
    8| contactName: contact.name ++ "XXX"
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Invalid function call `++(Null,String)` expected options:
```

I've not been able to figure out/find the right syntax to make the lambda happy again.

The following works fine so clearly there's something it's not liking about the return type of the concat when used in conjunction with contact.name (which has has type String?)

```
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
        theId: payload01.Id ,
        theName: payload01.Name,
        contacts: payload01.Contacts map ( contact , indexOfContact ) -> {
                contactName: contact.name,
                barf: "XXX" ++ "YYY"
        }
}
```

Comment: contact.name is `null`, so you're concatenating `null` with a `string`, which will throw a runtime error. You can either verify the string is not `null` beforehand using `if`/`else` to implement some conditional logic, or use `default` so that if the contact.name is `null` it will fall back on a string value of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following.

```
contactName: (contact.name default "") ++ "XXX"
```

DW is not smart enough to do the concatenation with static string and variable. Developer needs to check and concatenate it.

And most interesting thing is, this not mentioned in their [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/dataweave-operators#concat).

Comment: This will work, but it doesn't have much to do with "concatenation with static string and variable". The reason the OP's code isn't working is because contact.name is returning `null` and you can't apply `++` to `null`. Your `default` is changing the `null` to `""`, which you can call `++` on, because you're now applying `++` to two strings. This is mentioned in the doc you linked to, as it describes `++` as only being applicable to two arrays, or two strings, but not a null and a string, i.e., `(':array', ':array') ⇒ ':array'` and `(':string', ':string') ⇒ ':string'`